# in_array devuelve valores incorrectos

Tags: php, array, in-array

Tengo este simple código, para determinar si un elemento ya existe o no en un array previamente definido

```
$rutasUnicas = array();

$rutas = array(
    $xml->CODED_DATA_SECTION->NOTICE_DATA->IA_URL_GENERAL,
    $xml->CODED_DATA_SECTION->NOTICE_DATA->IA_URL_ETENDERING,
    $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_GENERAL,
    $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_BUYER,
    $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_DOCUMENT,
    $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_TOOL
);

foreach ($rutas as $ruta) {
    if ($ruta != '') {
        echo "revisando [$ruta]... >>>>> ";
        if (in_array($ruta, $rutasUnicas)){
            echo "YA EXISTE, la ignoramos<br>";
        } else {
            echo "no existe en el array, la insertamos<br>";
            array_push($rutasUnicas, $ruta);
        }
    }   
}

empty($rutasUnicas);
```

Este código devuelve esto por pantalla:

```
revisando [http://www.esm.europa.eu]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
revisando [https://www.esm.europa.eu/procurement]... >>>>> YA EXISTE, la ignoramos
revisando [http://www.esm.europa.eu]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
revisando [https://www.esm.europa.eu/procurement]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
```

Y esto es el contenido del array $arrayUnicos una vez terminan los foreach.

```
Array (
    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
        [0] => http://www.esm.europa.eu
    )

    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
        [0] => http://www.esm.europa.eu
    )

    [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
        [0] => https://www.esm.europa.eu/procurement
    )
)
```

Como véis, el array final tiene una dirección repetida, que no debería, además de haber agregado la segunda aparición de la segunda url, en vez de la primera aparición de la misma.

Qué estoy haciendo mal?

Answer (score 0):

Pienso que el error se debe a que no es lo mismo comparar un par de objetos **SimpleXMLElement** a comparar un par de cadenas. Puedes intentar comparando el contenido de `$arreglo` y no solamente los objetos. De la siguiente manera:

```
if (in_array($ruta[0], $rutasUnicas)){
    echo "YA EXISTE, la ignoramos<br>";
} else  {
    echo "no existe en el array, la insertamos<br>";
    array_push($rutasUnicas, $ruta[0]);
}
```

Comment: De esa manera no detecta en ningún caso que la url ya existe previamente. Me guarda las 4 rutas sin detectar que están repetidas 2 a 2.
Además la comparación entiendo que sí debería ser positiva en mi código, puesto que el texto entre corchetes es el contenido del SimpleXMLElement, y son iguales no? Lo que estoy comparando son los strings de resultado

Answer (score 0):

Finalmente encontré la solución.

Las rutas que aparecen dentro del array $rutas son objetos XML. Pese a que intenté comparar ambos objetos siempre resolvía mal, seguía sin detectar las repetidas correctamente, de forma que se me ocurrió forzar esas variables a ser de tipo string en el momento de ser capturadas para formar el array, con lo que a partir de ahí y siendo ya strings puros, la comparación resulta positiva cuando toca y negativa lo mismo.

```
    $rutasUnicas = array();

    $rutas = array(
            (string) $xml->CODED_DATA_SECTION->NOTICE_DATA->IA_URL_GENERAL,
            (string) $xml->CODED_DATA_SECTION->NOTICE_DATA->IA_URL_ETENDERING,
            (string) $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_GENERAL,
            (string) $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->ADDRESS_CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_BUYER,
            (string) $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_DOCUMENT,
            (string) $xml->FORM_SECTION->$sectionName->CONTRACTING_BODY->URL_TOOL
        );



        foreach ($rutas as $ruta) {
            if ($ruta != '') {
                echo "revisando [$ruta]... >>>>> ";
                if (in_array($ruta,$rutasUnicas, TRUE)) {
                    echo "YA EXISTE, la ignoramos<br>";
                }
                else  {
                    echo "no existe en el array, la insertamos<br>";
                    array_push($rutasUnicas, $ruta);
                }
            }   
        }

        empty($rutasUnicas);
```

Y aquí el resultado final:

```
revisando [https://tendering.consilium.europa.eu]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
revisando [https://etendering.ted.europa.eu/cft/cft-display.html?cftId=4335]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
revisando [https://tendering.consilium.europa.eu]... >>>>> YA EXISTE, la ignoramos
revisando [http://www.consilium.europa.eu/contacts/procurement]... >>>>> no existe en el array, la insertamos
revisando [https://etendering.ted.europa.eu/cft/cft-display.html?cftId=4335]... >>>>> YA EXISTE, la ignoramos
Array
(
    [0] => https://tendering.consilium.europa.eu
    [1] => https://etendering.ted.europa.eu/cft/cft-display.html?cftId=4335
    [2] => http://www.consilium.europa.eu/contacts/procurement
)
```

Comment: Exactamente, es lo que te proponia anteriormente, no manejar los objetos **SimpleXMLElement** sino **Strings**. Pero qué bueno que ya quedó resuelto. Saludos!